# MariaDB Connector/Node.js weird syntax error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb, mariadb-connector

The following function is being called for each POST request to an endpoint:

```
exports.resetall = async (req, res, next) => {
    let conn;

    try {
        conn = await pool.getConnection({multipleStatements: true});

        await conn.query(`
            SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

            SELECT @str := CONCAT('TRUNCATE TABLE ', table_schema, '.', table_name, ';')
            FROM   information_schema.tables
            WHERE  table_type   = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND    table_schema = DATABASE();

            PREPARE stmt FROM @str;

            EXECUTE stmt;

            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

            SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
        `);

        res.status(200).json({
            status: "OK"
        });
    } catch(err) {
        return next(err);
    } finally {
        if(conn) conn.end();
    }
};
```

Its purpose is to truncate all tables in the connected database.

However, the following SQL error occurs:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT @str := CONCAT('TRUNCATE TABLE ', table_schema, '.', table_name)\n     ...' at line 3

This happens only when running the SQL script above from within Node.js. Using any other SQL client, it works as it should.

I've tried a bunch of things like removing the semicolons, using DELETE FROM instead of TRUNCATE TABLE, removing newlines, removing the SET statements..

Nothing works.

***EDIT***

For those asking, here is how the connection pool is created:

```
const config = {
    http: {
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        port: 9103
    },

    mariadb: {
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        port: 3306,
        user: "intelliq",
        password: "",
        database: "intelliq"
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

```
const mariadb = require(`mariadb`);
const config = require(`../config`);

const pool = mariadb.createPool(config.mariadb);

module.exports = pool;
```

Comment: My guess is that the query() method cannot execute multiple sql statements by default.

Comment: I have used MariaDB a lot in the past, but I never used an “@“. What is it for?

Comment: Which node.js driver do you use? And how did you create pool ?

Comment: I am using the official MariaDB Connector/Node.js (https://mariadb.com/docs/skysql/connect/programming-languages/nodejs/)

Comment: The @ is for declaring user-defined variables

Comment: I edited the post to include the conn pool code, also if you see @Shadow I have enabled multiple statements for the connection in the 5th line of the first code block

Comment: @idressos actually, no, you do not enable multiple statement execution there. See the answer to the duplicate question for an explanation.